# get div id of selected div from loop with jquery

Tags: jquery, for-loop

Hi I have a form that looks like. (I have used sheepIt form clone but what I need is something like following).

```
   <div id="container">
     <% for i in loop %>
       //ex. 3 times loop could be test-1, test-2, test-3
       <div id="test-[i]">  
         "some content"
      </div>
     <% end loop %>
  </div>
```

Comment: $('#container').on('click', function(event) {var $div = $(event.target);  alert($div.prop('id');) } this is the code to access an clicked div. but i do not know what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$('#container').children().each(function(){
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
});
```